# Vue router-link and custom event

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm trying to make a custom event on a router-link in vue and it doesn't seem to be working. I want to do something like this-

parent-

```
<Home @customEvent="myEventHandler" />
```

script-

```
export default {
methods: {
    myEventHandler() {
        console.log('yay')
    }
}
```

child

```
export default {
...
mounted() {
    axios.get('api/link').then(res => {
        this.posts = res.data;
        this.$emit('customEvent')
    }
}
```

This works fine to create the log of yay with a regular component but when I try to do something like this-

```
<router-link to='/home' @customEvent="myEventHandler">Home</router-link>
```

It doesn't seem to work. How do you listen for custom events from a component thats created using router-link?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Why would you expect this to work? There's no child component of `<router-link>` to emit an event. Did you mean `<router-view>`?

Comment: It works- just didn't include that code

Comment: There is a separate router.js file that maps the component to the path- should I add the event listener there somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible. You can only `$emit` event from children to parent, you can't `$emit` event between 2 different router

> Emit event from children to parent
>
> [image]
>
> Can't emit event between 2 different routes:
>
> [image]

To work around this, you can create a wrapper component for both component A and component B, then using `router-view` to receive event